# Check if an order has been refunded in a template?

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce

What’s the best way to check if an order has been refunded in a template?

For example, you may want to:

- Add a message to the order/invoice template if a refund has been successful.
- Determine the status of the refund; perhaps displaying a different message if the status is not yet `success`.
- Show the time of refund.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the related transactions for an order with

`order.transactions`

So you can loop over the transactions like so:

```
{% for transaction in order.transactions %}
  {{ transaction.type|title }}
  {{ transaction.status|title }}
  {{ transaction.amount|currency(transaction.currency) }} ({{ transaction.currency }})
  {{ transaction.paymentMethod.name }}
  {{ transaction.dateUpdated|date }} // could also format to get the time
{% endfor %}
```

The transaction 'type' column can hold the following values:

`authorize, capture, purchase, refund`

The transaction 'status' column can hold the following values:

`pending, direct, success, failed`

Some of those transaction types have a 'parent' transaction, for example, if you authorized a credit card, you would have a authorize transaction. When you capture that authorization you get a capture transactions whose parent is the authorize transaction.

```
{{ transaction.type }} // could return 'refund'
{% set parent = transaction.parent %}
{{ parent.type }} // could return 'purchase' or 'capture'
```

Let me know if you have further questions and I will improve the answer.